# How to persist changes in Kubernetes? There are two files in the docker image that should update with every run

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I do have persistent volume and claim but I am unable to tell Kubernetes how to save these specific files. This is my deployment file, the files I want to persist are in the container root directory.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-first-cluster1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scrape
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: scrape
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: scraper
       
        image: asia-south1-docker.pkg.dev/erudite-stratum-338019/repo/scrape:latest
        #
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: PORT
          value: "8080"

        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/dev/shm"
          name: dshm
      volumes:
      - name: dshm
        emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
```

This is the persistent volume file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv-1
  labels:
    pv: my-pv-1
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: /
```

And, this is the PersistentVolumeClaim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: my-pvc-claim-1
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pv: my-pv-1
```

Comment: Can you rearrange your setup to store the data files in a dedicated directory, rather than the container root directory?  That would give you a place to mount a volume.  I'd also suggest using a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) here rather than creating the PersistentVolumeClaim yourself.  You shouldn't have to manually create the PersistentVolume at all.

Comment: Thanks this surely helps but how do I store the files in a dedicated directory? Sorry I am new to Kubernetes. They are in the image and running containers, how do i access them?

Comment: In your application code, where do you specify where to store the application data?  Make that be somewhere other than `/`, maybe just a `/data` directory.  Then you can mount the volume over that directory.

Comment: It is a scraping script, a data.db file and texdata.txt file updates with every run. Both files are in docker image and kubernetes containers. I didnt specify their path so by default they are in the root or "/" directory of running containers

Comment: You can't mount a volume over `/` since it would hide absolutely everything in the container.  You need to change the path in your application code to somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand why it was giving error earlier.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy  files from /root to Persistent volume [using LifeCycle hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/) ..

`PostStart LifeCycle event` get executed after container creation.

```
lifecycleHooks:postStart:exec:command.
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'll try it out.